# Функция glob() не замечает некоторые файлы

Tags: php

Функция `glob(path . '/*');` не замечает файлы, у которых в начале имени стоит точка. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Файлы с точкой в начале являются "скрытыми". Функция `glob` по умолчанию их не обрабатывает.

используйте такой шаблон:

```
$files = glob($path . '/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Теоретически, такой шаблон: `/{,.}*.php` должен найти все файлы php?

Comment: По идее да. Позвольте один вопрос, а зачем вам скрытые `.php` скрипты? Мне правда очень любопытно

Comment: нужно обработать их скриптом, сменить кодировку. Работаю в `Bitrix`, там таких файлов много.

Comment: При работе с битриксом можно воспользоваться `CFileMan::GetDirList`